# Incrementing values of more than one rows of SQLite table in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite database of Android which has a column **RANK**. It is in a game application. If some user get a rank, then it's rank should be inserted and the previously stored ranks should be incremented.

let **RANK** column has values **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9** and a new user gets a **RANK 3**, then I have to insert the new user's rank and increment the previous ranks. I mean **3 4 5 6 7 8 9** should be **4 5 6 7 8 9 10** and the newly created **3 RANK** should be inserted.

Is there any library method to do this? or i have to define custom logic?

Please help me. If custom logic is needed, then at least give some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this before inserting the new value, if 3 is the rank of the new value you're going to insert:

```
UPDATE player SET rank=rank+1 WHERE rank >= 3;
```

Before:

```
1|a
2|b
3|c
4|d
5|e
```

After:

```
1|a
2|b
4|c
5|d
6|e
```

Then you can insert the new one:

```
INSERT INTO player VALUES(3, "new");
```

Giving the final result:

```
SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY rank;

1|a
2|b
3|new
4|c
5|d
6|e
```

Comment: how to implement in android? update method takes ContentValues object for updating the values.

Comment: The `update` method is very well documented <http://goo.gl/72iuv>. If you are struggling to understand it, then I suggest you read a good tutorial.